# What is sourceline & resultline in git blame --incremental output?

Tags: git

From git blame [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame/1.6.0#_incremental_output):

> When called with `--incremental` option, the command outputs the result
>   as it is built. The output generally will talk about lines touched by
>   more recent commits first (i.e. the lines will be annotated out of
>   order) and is meant to be used by interactive viewers.
>
> The output format is similar to the Porcelain format, but it does not
>   contain the actual lines from the file that is being annotated.
>
> Each blame entry always starts with a line of:
>
> `<40-byte hex sha1> <sourceline> <resultline> <num_lines>`
>
> Line numbers count from 1.

I think the same pattern is used for `--porcelain` format where the [docs says](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#_the_porcelain_format):

> In this format, each line is output after a header; the header at the
>   minimum has the first line which has:
>
> - 40-byte SHA-1 of the commit the line is attributed to;
> - **the line number of the line in the original file;**
> - **the line number of the line in the final file;**
>
>   [...]

But everytime I run git blame with either of these options, `sourceline`(original line) and `resultline`(final line) are the same. I could understand these output in a git diff, but what does it mean in a git blame? How can I produce output where the `sourceline` and `resultline` differs?

Comment: I think i'm on to something, could it have to do with files being renamed? If a file has been renamed then the blame output could still refer to the line number in the old "original" file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was so obvious it is rather silly I didn't notice it.

- The *sourceline* is the line number the code was commited on.
- The *resultline* is the line number the code is now.

Example:

First commit of **index.html:**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Second commit of **index.html** (4 new lines added):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            Hello World!
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

then the output of `git blame --incremental index.html` will look like this:

```
f0a2d579be45dc1283672b4750bdc1923a9f7b2d 10 10 5
...
summary Hello World
previous ce3f4934051212a78c2fed853a113e2223428809 index.html
filename index.html
ce3f4934051212a78c2fed853a113e2223428809 1 1 9
...
summary initial commit
boundary
filename index.html
ce3f4934051212a78c2fed853a113e2223428809 11 15 2
filename index.html
```

Note that the output specifies that the 2 lines that **were** on line 11 & 12 when they were commited (`</body>` & `</html>`) now are on line 15 & 16.

This works the same way for the `--porcelain` output.

I guess I didn't test this enough before asking the question, must have only test on files where code has been appended to the end of the file.